# Swift: modifying data format through a button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

**My goal is to use a button (that contains multiple messages) to trigger a text (making a marker such as first click will be method 1, second click will be method 2) correspondingly added at the end of the my data (after joined(separator: "~")) so that it could help me to analyze which button was clicked when I look back at the data.**

Currently, I have a struct that will output the data:

```
struct CaptureData {
var vertices: [SIMD3<Float>] //A vector of three scalar values. It will return a list of [SIMD3<Float>(x,y,z)]
var mode: Mode = .one
mutating func nextCase() { // the data method will be changed
    mode = mode.next()
}
var verticesFormatted : String {  //I formatted in such a way so that it can be read more clearly without SIMD3
let v = "<" + vertices.map{ "\($0.x):\($0.y):\($0.z)" }.joined(separator: "~") + "trial: \(mode.next().rawValue)"
        return "\(v)"
    }
}
```

Based on @Joshua suggestion

```
enum Mode: String, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three
}
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }
    var nextCase: Self {
        let index = allCases.index(after: allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!)
        guard index != allCases.endIndex else { return allCases.first! }
        return allCases[index]
    }
    @discardableResult
    func next() -> Self {
        return self.nextCase
    }
}
```

And the button is alternating the messages after each click,

```
  var x = 0
  var instance = CaptureData(vertices: [SIMD3<Float>])
// Next button for changing methods
@IBAction func ChangingTapped(_ btn: UIButton) {
  if(x==0){
      Textfield.text = "changing to driving"
  }
  else if(x==1){
       Textfield.text = "changing to walking"
     instance.nextCase()
  }
  else{
     Textfield.text = "changing to cycling"
     instance.nextCase()
  }
   x += 1
}
```

**Updates: I am able to print one of the methods , .two (method two), after separator: "~". However, at the moment I am still not be able to click button to switch the case in the data.**

The main problem is the initialization of variables. I am not able to define `var instance = CaptureData(vertices: [SIMD3<Float>])` because it comes with error: `Cannot convert value of type '[SIMD3<Float>].Type' to expected argument type '[SIMD3<Float>]'`

I am sorry if my explanation is a bit messy here. I am trying to describe the problem I have here. Let me know if there is anything missing! Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: shouldn't the mutation happen in the struct not in the enum?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am a bit new to swift and trying my best to learn at the moment. Do you mean putting mutating the mode or v in the struct? Could you direct me a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums is a data type that is more like a constant but much more readable.

An example will be passing in a status to a function.

```swift
enum Status {
   case success
   case failure
}

func updateStatus(_ status: Status) {
    statusProperty = status
}

// somewhere in your code
instance.updateStatus(.success)
```

versus using an Int as a value.

```swift
func updateStatus(_ status: Int) {
    statusProperty = status
}

// somewhere in your code
instance.updateStatus(1) // eventually you'll forget what this and you'll declare more of a global variable acting as constant, which technically what enums are for.
```

Enums in swift are a bit different though, much more powerful. More info about enums [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)

Back to the topic.

```swift
enum Mode: String, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three
}

extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }
    var nextCase: Self {
        let index = allCases.index(after: allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!)
        guard index != allCases.endIndex else { return allCases.first! }
        return allCases[index]
    }

    @discardableResult
    func next() -> Self { // you don't need to update self here, remember self here is one of the items in the enum, i.e. one, so assigning one = two just doesn't work.
        return self.nextCase
    }
}

// The data struct
struct CaptureData {
    var mode: Mode = .one
   // we add a mutation function here so we can update the mode
    mutating func nextCase() { // the data your concern about, that can actually mutate is the mode property inside CaptureData struct. 
        mode = mode.next()
    }
}
```

So lets say somewhere in the app you can use it like this you initialised an instance of CaptureData:

```swift
var instance = CaptureData() // Don't forget it should be var and not let, as we are updating its property.
instance.nextCase() // get the next case, initially it was .one
print(instance.mode) // prints two
instance.nextCase() // from .two, changes to .three
print(instance.mode) // prints three
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @Joshua, thank you so much for the response! I was able to fix the mutating error in the struct. I tried to implement var instance = CaptureData() into my UIbutton to switch the cases after clicking. However, now I was not able to do CaptureData() as you indicated because of  var vertices: [SIMD3<Float>]. I uploaded that. Could I ask you whether that method is that work for my case? (I also tried var instance = CaptureData(vertices: [SIMD3<Float>])

Comment: as long as the initialisation of CaptureData is outside of your IBAction, just like the var x you did.  THe initialisation of CaptureData is how you pointed out, you need to pass in the diff vertices, i.e. CaptureData(vertices: [<some values>]). then all functions of that instance should be accessible inside IBAction. did That clear things up?

Comment: Hello @Joshua, Thank you for your time and I hope I am not interrupting you so much and asking you the proper questions. I did try putting var instance = CaptureData(vertices: [SIMD3<Float>]) like so in the edited version but it comes up with error that I could not solve even after googling. It said Cannot convert value of type '[SIMD3<Float>].Type' to expected argument type '[SIMD3<Float>]'

Comment: At the moment it just show .two at the end of the data. I was expecting .one? I hope to trigger that after each click so I put instance.nextCase() for each case like so. I thank you very much for your time and patience

Comment: all good, can you add edits to your post, on what has changed, how you are calling CaptureData instance? need to understand what you are doing to encounter those issues.

Comment: @swiftLearneer I see what the issue is. I think you need to understand how to initialised things. CaptureData expects a list of vertices. i.e. CaptureData(vertices: [SIMD3(1), SIMD(2)]) I don't know what SIMD3 is actually, so Im expecting it to be initialised like this? Read more on initialisation of variables.

Comment: Sounds good! I will update to what I have including your suggestion. Might be we can go from there!

Comment: Thanks for your time @Joshua! I edited what I have and the problem that I am dealing with. I hope its the same topic such that my question is not too off from the original topic. I will take a look on initialization of variables and see whether I can figure that one out.

Comment: Just a quick update here as I was reading about initialization. I think you are right @Joshua. The problem I have now is because of SIMD3 initialization. Using SIMD3 would allow me to get the x,y,z vertices and formatted them (Originally from the example it was var vertices: [float3] but its now depreciated). However, I just could not find a proper way to set the instance and call the Capture struct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215703/discussion-between-joshua-and-swiftlearneer).